# Excel 2007 - External Datasources (Tables) Changing Absolute Ranges

Tags: excel-2007

Excel 2007 is driving me nuts.  I have several charts set up that I refresh periodically against some data in a SQL database.  However, every time I refresh them, Excel bumps any absolute ranges I have for the charts to view this data by the amount of new records returned from the query.

The data is time related (I have a record for each minute of the day), and I want the chart (line chart) to be fixed in size... instead, Excel wants it to dynamically change, and thus it adds the extra rows to my named ranges.

Is there a way to prevent Excel from updating absolute named ranges when new data from a data source is returned?  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

How are you defining your named ranges?  I'm assuming your are just using cell references, if so it may be worth looking at the [offset](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324991) function, particularly if you are dealing with fixed size ranges (e.g. minutes in a day).

For example, if you had column headers in the first row, your minutes were in column A and you had exactly 1 row for each minute your offset formula would look like:

```
OFFSET(A2,0,0,1,1440)
```

and is defined as

```
OFFSET(StartCell, OffsetRows, OffsetCols, Width, Height)
```

Because any of the values within the arguments can also be formulas, OFFSET is a very useful function in defining ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... that does not seem to work.  For example, if I have one sheet with the table data and another with the chart and I assign a named range to the sheet like so =OFFSET(DataSheet!$C$2,390,0) to capture 390 rows of data starting from C2, I don't get any data in the series... am I missing something?

Comment: Your offset function isn't correct, it needs 5 values - if your data starts at cell C2, and is 390 rows long you will probably need to use OFFSET(DataSheet!$C$2,0,0,1,390) which is saying 'start at cell C2, move 0 cells across and 0 cells down, and take a region 1 cell wide and 390 high'